# Sculpt mode - pink shading

Tags: sculpting

I am trying to do some sculpting on the icing of this donut but when I switch to *sculpt mode* I get this weird violet shading.
Did it happen to somebody before?
[image]

Rgds

Comment: your file would help more, it looks like it is divided on edges, maybe it is some texture, uv problem, different material or it can be sculpt mask, many possibilities

Answer (score 1):

It's probably *Face Sets*, which are sort of masks, you can remove it: Go into the header menu > *Face Sets > Initialize Face Sets > By Loose Parts*.

[image]

Comment: SOLVED. It was Face Sets. Thanks.